# Extracting non-overlapping polygons in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am trying to perform what I thought ought to be a simple operation in PostGIS. I would like to use a set of circle polygons to split a set of square polygons and extract the resulting non-overlapping polygons. I have drawn a simplistic version of this below. I would like to extract non-overlapping polygons representing areas A, B, C, D, E, F, and G. Note that the datasets involved are large with tens of thousands of circles.

[image: Problem representation]

I have tried using ST_Intersection but that gives me overlapping polygons.
I have tried reducing those overlapping polygons to lines and re-creating non-overlapping polygons (using ST_Boundary, ST_Union and ST_Polygonize) this works initially but then gives me Topology exceptions ('ERROR:  GEOSUnaryUnion: TopologyException: found non-noded intersection between LINESTRING xx and LINESTRING xx'. I'm guessing due to issues with excess coordinate places) when I start running it for very large numbers of circles. I have tried getting rid of the topology errors using ST_MakeValid, ST_Node, ST_Buffer(geom,0), ST_SnapToGrid etc. as suggested elsewhere on here, all with no success.

So can anyone provide an alterative approach to solving this, seemingly simple problem? I get the feeling I'm missing something obvious here and getting too lost in trying to unpick the topology exception when I think there ought to be a simplier solution to the intersect.

Comment: Have a look at this blog post - the technique can be adapted:    http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2019/07/postgis-overlays.html

Comment: Have you tried `st_difference`?  To use it, you would union all the geom for the circles, then set the geom on the polygons to `st_difference(poly.geom, allcircles.geom)`

Comment: something like `select st_difference(poly.geom, allcircles.geom), poly.id from your_poly_table poly, (select st_union(geom) from your_circles_table) allcircles;`

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood the question.  I think `st_split` may actually be useful.  Something like this `select st_split(poly.geom, circlelines.geom), poly.id from your_poly_table poly, (select st_union(st_exteriorring(geom)) from your_circle_table) circlelines;`

Comment: I forgot to note that you'll need to either dump or extract the resulting geometry collection after the split - `st_collectionextract(st_split(poly.geom, allcircles.geom), 3)` or `(st_dump(st_split(poly.geom, allcircles.geom))).geom`

Comment: Thank you - this ST_Split solution works nicely. However, I do seem to run out of memory now when I use very large numbers of circles.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [PostGIS Addons](https://github.com/pedrogit/postgisaddons) and run this query:

```
WITH rectangletable AS (
  SELECT 1 id, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 0 3, 2 3, 2 0, 0 0))') geom
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 id, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((3 0, 3 3, 5 3, 5 0, 3 0))') geom
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 id, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((6 0, 6 3, 8 3, 8 0, 6 0))') geom
), circletable AS (
  SELECT 1 id, ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(4 3)'), 2.5) geom
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 id, ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(4 0)'), 2.5) geom
)
, splitted AS (
  SELECT unnest(ST_SplitAgg(a.geom, b.geom)) geom
  FROM rectangletable a,
       circletable b
  WHERE ST_Equals(a.geom, b.geom) OR
        ST_Contains(a.geom, b.geom) OR
        ST_Contains(b.geom, a.geom) OR
        ST_Overlaps(a.geom, b.geom)
  GROUP BY ST_AsEWKB(a.geom)
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ST_AsEWKB(geom)) geom
FROM splitted;
```

If it works as expected, replace the two tables with your own tables. That would become simply:

```
WITH splitted AS (
  SELECT unnest(ST_SplitAgg(a.geom, b.geom)) geom
  FROM rectangletable a,
       circletable b
  WHERE ST_Equals(a.geom, b.geom) OR
        ST_Contains(a.geom, b.geom) OR
        ST_Contains(b.geom, a.geom) OR
        ST_Overlaps(a.geom, b.geom)
  GROUP BY ST_AsEWKB(a.geom)
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ST_AsEWKB(geom)) geom
FROM splitted;
```

Comment: Thank you Pierre Racine. I will look into whether this is possible on the linux setup I am using.

Comment: @Ddee [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Ddee Upvote and accept the answer.